# How to make a resize with ImageMagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I need to create a thumb image of a remote jpeg image

Comment: That's interesting. What is your question?

Comment: In order to get a good answer, you'll need to put more into your question. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is rather general. There is a PHP tool called [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) that comfortably takes care of resizing and caching local and remote images. Once set up and configured, it is a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

try using system:

```
system("convert <pathToImageToResize> -resize 64x64  <outputPath>");
```

for a remote picture you would need to fetch it, resize it, and then provide that image

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as downloading it, and then invoking the -resize thingy:

```
copy("http://example.com/image.jpeg", "img1.jpeg");
exec("mogrify -resize 50x50 img1.jpeg");
```

Take care with the file permissions and whatnot.